# JDBC It does not run with a specific column name and I do not get it why?

Tags: java, jdbc

If I type this:

```
try {
    ResultSet rs = dbmd.getTables(null, "APP", "USERS", null);
    if(!rs.next()) {
        state.execute("create table users(first varchar(20), last varchar(20))");
    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    System.out.println("Problem RS");
    System.out.println(""+ex);
}
```

It gives this error:

```
ThirdConnection
conn OK
state OK
dbmd OK
Problem RS
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "first" at line 1, column 20.
```

If I change the code to

```
state.execute("create table users(name varchar(20), address varchar(20))");
```

->

```
ThirdConnection
conn OK
state OK
dbmd OK
rs OK
```

More details needed even if the question is fine so I would like to ask: Why?

Comment: first and last are SQL keywords. Choose other names (and don't choose table, select or order :))

Comment: Right... Thanks for fast answer... I was like I am gonna jump out of windows because had no idea why it is not working...

Comment: @Lino: `\`first\``  is invalid SQL. Keywords need to be quoted with double quotes in SQL, e.g: `"first"` but it's better to find a name that isn't a keyword

Comment: It makes life a lot easier if you specify which database you tried. Reserved keywords vary from database from database.